# Finding ports opened for a given PID programmatically

Tags: python, linux, bash, process, port

In Linux, given a PID, is there a way to find the list of ports it opened programmatically (preferably Python)? Utilities such as lsof/netstat not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?  Note: **needs to run w/ sudo-rights**, otherwise you have no access to the `PIDs`.

```
import psutil
tmp = psutil.net_connections()
for i in tmp:
    if i.pid==30264:
        print( i.laddr[1] )
```

P.S.: You weren't clear on whether you meant local or remote ports; adjust `laddr` to `raddr` accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for remote connections.